# Extra space getting added while reading the text in TJ operator

Tags: pdf

```
0.99 0 0 -1 1409 77 Tm
[(Filer) -48.4848 (oS) -33.3333 (earchE) -47.4747 (xpres) -36.3636 (si)
 -44.4444 (on_bp) -37.3737 (:)] TJ
0.99 0 0 -1 1827 77 Tm
[(bp)] TJ
```

The actual sentence is "FileroSearchExpression_bp:bp" but if I take the xposition (FileroSearchExpression_bp:) + length(FileroSearchExpression_bp:), it is nower nearest to xposition of second TJ operator and because of this an extra space is getting added.

Does -1 in Textmatrix have any significance?

Comment: The x scale in the textmatrix is set to 99%; are you adjusting for that? It's hard to say without seeing *any* of your code. (BTW, the `-1` there is just the vertical 'scale'; this inverts the y axis.)

Comment: What is the issue? If you want the **TJ** arguments printed without gap, simply throw away the **Tm** operation located in-between. If you want us to verify your width calculations, you have to present the context of that content stream excerpt and your code.